# Create multiple files using parameters from function using results from ThreadPool executor

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I have a simple function that collects the inventory of cards in several pieces of networking gear.  I am using the executor.map to call the function and produce the results.  This all works fine.  However, I need to write the results to different files.  Ideally I would like to have a filename for each node that I'm collecting the inventory on.  So something like node1-inventory.txt, node2-inventory.txt and so on.  I can't figure out how to include the node name in the file name when I loop through the results and write them to the file.  My output would be node1-inventory.txt, node2-inventory.txt and so on.

```
def get_node_inventory(node_name):
    with Ta5kTelnet() as tlnt:
        tlnt.login(node_name, 'username', 'password')
        shelf_inventory = tlnt.send_command(b"show system inventory", b"#")
        return shelf_inventory

nodes = [node1, node2, node3]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_node_inventory, nodes)

    for result in results:
        with open(node-name + "-inventory.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return a tuple with the node name and the result instead of just the result.

```
def get_node_inventory(node_name):
    with Ta5kTelnet() as tlnt:
        tlnt.login(node_name, "username", "password")
        shelf_inventory = tlnt.send_command(b"show system inventory", b"#")
        return (node_name, shelf_inventory)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_node_inventory, [node1, node2, node3])

    for (node_name, result) in results:
        with open(node_name + "-inventory.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(result)
```

Alternately, you can also write to the different files in your worker threads. I've switched to `multiprocessing` here to use `imap_unordered` since this task shouldn't care about execution order.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


def get_node_inventory(node_name):
    with Ta5kTelnet() as tlnt:
        tlnt.login(node_name, "username", "password")
        return tlnt.send_command(b"show system inventory", b"#")


def write_node_inventory(node_name):
    inventory = get_node_inventory(node_name)
    with open(node_name + "-inventory.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(result)


with ThreadPool() as pool:
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(write_node_inventory, [node1, node2, node3]):
        pass
```

Comment: I thought this was working but I'm running into an issue and need some help troubleshooting.  The script starts off fine and files are being created.  Then script throws the below error and quits.  Is there a way to see which thread is causing this error?

Comment: This is the error.  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 1854: invalid start byte

Comment: The `tlnt` instance returns a bytes (binary) response and it happens to contain something that can't be represented as UTF-8. Either add `errors="replace"` to `open()` _or_ change the file mode from `"w"` (write text) to `"wb"` (write binary) so Python won't try to do UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually decided to go with your alternative solution and it works with no issues.  I haven't tested changing the (write text) in the original solution yet.